# How to programmatically connect and disconnect twitter account to my website

Tags: cakephp, twitter

I would like to provide option to programmatically connect and disconnect my twitter account from my application. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: To achieve what exactly? What are you trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to twitter using their [API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs). If you search google, I'm sure there are tons of plugins/helpers/components/behaviors/datasources written in cakephp to connect to the twitter api.

Through the api, you'll be able to list tweets, followers, followings, send a tweet, etc.